# How to determine cis or trans for an alkene?

Tags: stereochemistry

I was doing some practice problems for an exam this week, and I came across a molecule that I swear is trans, but the book says it doesn't exhibit any stereoismerism. I got every other question right (or at least figured out why I got it wrong), but I can't figure this one out.

Here's a picture of the molecule:

[image]

As you can see, it has two butyl groups extending to the left and right of the central pi bond, doesn't that make it trans?

Answer (score 8):

In the example you've given, *both* groups on the right hand side of the alkene are equivalent (*n*-butyl) meaning its impossible to tell them apart (and hence you can't assign a priority to either one.

[image]

The situation would be different if we were considering two of the same groups bonded to different sides of the alkene.

[image]

In the example above we can now say that the two butyl groups are either *cis* or *trans* to one another, since both sides of the alkene can be distinguished (on each side of the alkene, we can assign a group of higher priority).  Note that E/Z may be more appropriate here.

Comment: And note that cyclohexyl has a higher priority than *n*-butyl.